# S7-1500 communication with SCADA system

Tags: communication

I'm working with a client who are in the process of installing a smart waste solution in a new building. This solution will be using s7-1500 PLC and ET200SP as remote I/O units. The communication between PLC and I/O units will be using modbus master/slave (CM PtP, RS485). This system needs to communicate with a top system (central operation) based on Schneider teknology running with modbus.
My question: what is the best way to setup this communication between ths PLC and the top system?

Comment: there are quite a bit of available libraries for SCADA protocols. I would suggest to look for a widely used library and use it, if it fits your needs

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.